# PILLOW enhance module messing up HTML Canvas destination out image

Tags: image, python-2.7, html5-canvas, python-imaging-library

As a part of an experiment I'm trying to process images edited in . I am erasing parts of the image like a brush by drawing on it with

> ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";

I'm converting this canvas to image with ctx.toDataURL() and saving this in the server with a base64 conversion. So the saved image at this stage looks like this:

[image]

The white areas are actually transparent. Now I'm putting this same through the Pillow imageEnhance module:

```
    path   = imgName
    imObj  = Image.open(imgName)
    enhObj = ImageEnhance.Contrast(imObj)
    enhObj.enhance(factor).show()
```

Though the contrast adjustment has happened properly this is how the image looks:

[image]

Any idea why this is happening and how to tackle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a problem with the application show() is calling which in this case is some Imagemagick viewer. Once saved to disk the image rendered properly. The problem with lossy transparency however still exists with desaturation through ImageEngance.color() module.